# Is EventMachine required for sending async http requests in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading, asynchronous

Using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2, My goal is to

1)  Start 2 async http requests, `req1` and `req2`.

2)  While these are waiting for a response, do some other processing.

3)  Once we receive a response from `req1` we need to process it and wait for `req2` to return.  If `req2` returns first, wait for `req1` to finish and then process that before processing the returned data from `req2`.

I've tried doing it with threads, but it appears that I can't do anything until the threads both return a response.  I believe it is possible to do accomplish what I want with EventMachine, but I'd rather avoid that if there is a preferable solution that I don't know about.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: look at https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Comment: I don't think typhoeus meets the requirements because IO is blocked after the requests are sent, so i wouldnt be able to accomplish (2) while waiting for the responses

Answer (score 0):

you can use Celluloid:io for that or fibers.